# Websocket object in a non-browser javascript environment

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, paho

I am trying to use a JavaScript client library(Paho) in a JavaScript engine which is neither in a Node Js environment nor a browser environment. The client library assumes a browser environment and directly uses objects such as 'WebSockets', 'LocalStorage' etc. which are reported as 'not defined' when I run them in the context of my JS engine. Is there a direct way to simulate a browser environment with the browser objects defined in my JavaScript Client code/ Engine? Alternatively can I fetch the scripts containing the object definitions of these classes and manually import them in my client?

Comment: localStorage should be there, for socket connections you need a socket client like socket.io

Comment: I have checked for localStorage and it is not provided by my JavaScript Engine. I am using the JInt Engine which executes the code using .NET Framework. I am aware of libraries like Socket IO which provide WebSockets support but that would mean I have to edit the Paho JavaScript library which I am avoiding for now. Basically I would prefer to import the scripts which browsers such as Firefox themselves use.

Comment: Socket.io does not provide websocket support. Rather, it is a message passing that uses websocket or ajax. If your engine does not provide either websocket or ajax then socket.io will simply not work because it can't use what it needs.

Comment: Thank you. This leaves me even deeper into the dark though. I was under the impression that since Firefox is open source I will be able to fetch the scripts they use. But all I find is documentation for the API and no actual definition.